# How to read Lightning Files (ContentVersion data) using Salesforce Functions?

Tags: salesforce-functions

This appears like a duplicate of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365978/unable-to-read-content-files-within-organization-using-salesforce-functions), but it is not. I am looking to read the contents of a file attachment (ContentVersion) in Salesforce.

```
package com.example;

import com.salesforce.functions.jvm.sdk.Context;
import com.salesforce.functions.jvm.sdk.InvocationEvent;
import com.salesforce.functions.jvm.sdk.SalesforceFunction;
import com.salesforce.functions.jvm.sdk.data.Record;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;

public class FileManagerFunction implements SalesforceFunction<FunctionInput, FunctionOutput>{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(X9managerFunction.class);

    @Override
    public FunctionOutput apply(InvocationEvent<FunctionInput> event, Context context) throws Exception {
        String parentId = "a0hf000000EQ8eEAAT";
        String contentDocumentLinkQuery = "SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '" + parentId + "'";
        List<Record> contentDocumentLinks = context.getOrg().get().getDataApi().query(contentDocumentLinkQuery).getRecords();
        LOGGER.info(">>> Function successfully queried {} X9 contentDocumentLinks!", contentDocumentLinks.size());

        String contentDocumentId = null;
        String linkedEntityId = null;

        for(Record record : contentDocumentLinks) {
            contentDocumentId = record.getStringField("ContentDocumentId").get();
            linkedEntityId = record.getStringField("LinkedEntityId").get();
        }

        LOGGER.info(">>> X9 contentDocumentId = " + contentDocumentId);

        String contentVersionQuery = "SELECT ContentDocumentId, VersionData, Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '" + contentDocumentId + "' AND IsLatest = true";
        List<Record> contentVersions = context.getOrg().get().getDataApi().query(contentVersionQuery).getRecords();
        LOGGER.info(">>> Function successfully queried {} X9 contentVersions!", contentVersions.size());

        String contentVersionData = null;
        byte[] decoded = null;

        for(Record record : contentVersions){
        //********* HOW CAN I EXTRACT VersionData TO A byte[] BELOW? *********
            contentVersionData = record.getStringField("VersionData").get(); //or is it record.getByteField("VersionData").get()?

            byte[] bytes = contentVersionData.getBytes("UTF-8");
            String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
            decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
        }

        LOGGER.info(">>> X9 contentVersionData = " + contentVersionData);
        return null;
    }   
}
```

When I do as above, I get a path:

> /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/

as opposed to the actual file content. How do I fix this so I end up with a byte[]?